# NetBeans autocomplete & PHP; force __get() type

Tags: php, class, netbeans, methods, autocomplete

Quick one on NetBeans 7.0 and autocomplete for PHP;

I'm trying to figure out (*if possible*) how to force `__get()` implemented in a class to return (*refer to*) a certain type, the type being the same class in which `__get()` is implemented, always.

Right now, I have (*in `View`*):

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @return View
 */
public function __get($key){
    return $this->getView($key);
}
```

Accessed like so:

```
$view->foo-> // should populate with methods from View
            ^
```

Now I've been reading about the `@property`, but I'm not sure if that's correct for what I'm doing. The other thing is (*and this would be a nice feature if possible*) typically views are nested, so it's not uncommon in my implementation to see this:

```
$view->foo->bar->baz-> // should populate with methods from View
                      ^
```

Any idea on how to force this, or am I stuck?

---

**Update:**

So `@property` seems to be heading the correct direction, however there doesn't seem to be support for wildcarding the property names. So to elaborate on my question, does anyone know of any NetBeans plugins, or undocumented (*or just plain hard to find*) PHPDoc syntax for supporting wildcard `@property` names?

I'm thinking in one of these directions:

```
/**
 * @property View *
 * @property View ...
 * @property View $var,...
 */
```

Of course, none of these variations work, however the last would seem most logical, as they seem to support a similar syntax for variadic function parameter lists.

Comment: I haven't see any IDE that works properly with magic methods.

Comment: You probably can code some sort of add-on for you, maybe something that assigns type `View` to all unrecognized properties of `View`.

Comment: Well that's just darn unfortunate. Specifically because I'm not Java-savvy and wouldn't know where to start with plugin development (*though that would be sweet*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Netbeans can work that magic for you with the `@property` like shown in the example below.

As you already have figured out you will have to define each property in the doc block.

Another possible solution for your `$x->y->z->view` example is listed below.

#### Copy & paste this into Netbeans and it will show the methods of the Bar class:

```
<?php

/**
 * @property Bar $prop
 */
class foo {

}

class bar {
    public function xyz() {

    }

    public function abc() {

    }
}

$x = new foo();
$x->prop->
```

When you move the cursor here and press ctrl+space you will see:

[image: netbeans intellisense with @property]

---

If you want autocomplete for a longer resulton chain you can also use

```
/** @var Viewclass $foo */
$foo = $x->y->z->view;
$foo->autoCompleteWorksNow();
```

anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks @edorian - Yea, I've figured out that much, however (*and this is a long shot I'm sure*) is there any way to force **all** visible properties to act this way? Some such syntax as `@property Bar *`?

Comment: Also; your font size is rather massive. I believe I read somewhere that this is a "*good practice*" as it encourages shorter method bodies, any validity there?

Comment: @tomcatExodus None that i know of at least; For the font size: I can see around 45 lines on a screen. Thats enough for any method I'd `like` read :) And well, it makes pairing much easier when you don't have to cuddle to read everything. Thats the main reason ;)